# LookupOrderedRows function reutrning 'System.Data.DataRow[]'

Tags: ampscript, lookup

I have the below ampscript to lookup the most recent purchase by the date based field "updated_date".

```
    %%[
        SET @SFCRMID = _subscriberkey
        SET @orderId = LookupOrderedRows("Pro_Post_Purchase_Journey_SubKeyMig", 1, "updated_date DESC", "ORDERNUMBER", @SFCRMID)
        IF RowCount(@orderId) > 0 THEN
        SET @row = Row(@orderId, 1)
        SET @recentOrderNumber = Field(@row, "ORDERNUMBER")
    ]%%
```

When previewing a user on the DE "Pro_Post_Purchase_Journey_SubKeyMig" I receive the below message for the orderId value.

OrderID: System.Data.DataRow[]

Comment: It's normal since this function returns a set of ordered rows. You need to use `Row` and `Field` functions to retrieve the field value like you did with the "ORDERNUMBER"

Comment: No value is being pulled for @recentOrderNumber. The users being previewed are on the "Pro_Post_Purchase_Journey_SubKeyMig" DE so there is an ORDERNUMBER associated with that user.